# Can Harvey Walters solve the final rune puzzle with his special ability?

Tags: mansions-of-madness

Harvey Walters has a special ability that allows him to solve any rune puzzle once per game for a certain cost (can't remember exactly).

One of the scenarios requires the investigators to solve a rune puzzle to win. Can Harvey Walters just use this ability to win the game (which seems very anti-climatic)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nowhere mentionning you cannot use the character's power against the "boss"

I would find it rather hard to believe you can use the statuette that reduces the boss's damage to harvey to 1 but couldnt save the 1shot power versus the "boss puzzle"

Anti-climactic yes, but then again what's the point of wasting a good power to get a 1shot use if you cannot use it when it really counts